# Load multiple resource files in Webpack for use in messageformat.js

Tags: webpack, messageformat.js

I have a [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) [loader](http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html) called [`messageformat-loader`](https://github.com/cletusw/messageformat-loader) that takes in JSON, passes it through [messageformat.js](https://github.com/messageformat/messageformat.js), and outputs the resulting map of format functions. It works fine with a single file.

*./simple-messages.json*

```json
{
  "simple-example": "A simple message.",
}
```

*./example.js*

```js
var messages = require('messageformat?locale=en!json!./simple-messages.json');
console.log(messages['simple-example']());
```

*To run*

```js
$ npm install webpack messageformat-loader messageformat@1.0.0-rc.3 json-loader
$ node_modules/.bin/webpack ./example.js bundle.js
<...omitted webpack output...>
$ node bundle.js
A simple message.
```

messageformat.js's [CLI](https://messageformat.github.io/build/#cli-compiler), however, accepts a glob of files, which it then aggregates into one JSON object using the name of the file as its key before passing it through the compiler.

How would I accomplish this using `webpack` since globs aren't supported?

*./multi-example.js*

```js
var messages = require('messageformat?locale=en!json!./*.json');
console.log(messages['simple-messages']['simple-example']());
```

*To run*

```js
$ node_modules/.bin/webpack ./multi-example.js bundle.js
<...omitted webpack output...>

ERROR in ./multi-example.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./*.json in <path>/test123
 @ ./multi-example.js 1:15-63
<path>/test123/bundle.js:47
  var messages = __webpack_require__(!(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \"messageformat?locale=en!json!./*.json\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }()));

Error: Cannot find module "messageformat?locale=en!json!./*.json"
    at webpackMissingModule (<path>/test123/bundle.js:47:81)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<path>/test123/bundle.js:47:195)
    at __webpack_require__ (<path>/test123/bundle.js:20:30)
    at <path>/test123/bundle.js:40:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (<path>/test123/bundle.js:43:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
```

---

My attempts:

- Apply the glob in `webpack.config.js` itself (as recommended [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/370#issuecomment-49835937))

  - How do I aggregate the results and pass them into `messageformat-loader`? If I don't, I'll have `messageformat.js`'s runtime included once for each JSON file.

    - It looks like this may actually be the better approach, but I'd have to modify messageformat.js's output to [separate the runtime](https://webpack.github.io/docs/how-to-write-a-loader.html#extract-common-code) from the strings.
- Use `require.context` (as recommended [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/370#issuecomment-171832674))

  - See above
- [`multi-json-loader`](https://github.com/cletusw/multi-json-loader)

  - Unfortunately, this is awkward because webpack requires a resource file even if it isn't used

    ```js
    require('messageformat?locale=en!multi-json?cwd=data&glob=**/*.json!./irrelevant.whatever')
    ```
  - I could move the glob into the resource file, like [`glob-loader`](https://github.com/seanchas116/glob-loader#dirpattern-file), but having parameters to your loader be pulled from a source file seems even more awkward to me.

    - This is what [fontgen-loader](https://github.com/DragonsInn/fontgen-loader#usage) also does, so this looks like a common approach.
- Should I make a `messageformat-plugin` instead of a loader? Then I'd have full control over the chunks. This feels like the wrong abstraction, though.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is what is called a "resolver" plugin ( in combination with your webpack loader). Pairing a plugin and a loader isn't off limits (see extract text plugin :-).

```
compiler.resolvers.normal.plugin('resolve', function resolverPlugin(request, cb) {
  ... 
});
```